# Sending an array of objects in a mutation using graphQL

Tags: graphql

On my server, I've this:

```
extend type Mutation {
    setMySkills (skills: [
        SkillUpdated!
    ]!) : [MySkills]
}
    input SkillUpdated {
    name: String, 
    id: Int, 
    order: Int!, 
    fromMonth:Int!,
    fromYear:Int, 
    toMonth:Int, 
    toYear: Int
}
type MySkills {
    name: String!,
    id: Int!,
    order: Int!,
    from: String!,
    to: String,
    minYear: Int!
}
```

I am trying to perform a mutation operation using the playground. Something like this:

```
mutation setMySkills($skills: [SkillUpdated!]!) {
  setMySkills(skills: $skills) {
  id
  name
  order
  from
  to
  minYear
}
}
```

Variables:

```
{
  "skills": [
  {
    "name": "Driving"
    "id": 7
    "order": 506
    "fromMonth": 0
    "fromYear": 1986
    "toMonth": 0
    "toYear": 1993
  }
 ]
}
```

But it's not working...

"Variable \"$skills\" of required type \"[SkillUpdated!]!\" was not provided."

Any help ?

Comment: Your query and variables appear valid. If you're using GraphQL Playground, it has a toggle for the variables and the HTTP headers. It's easy to accidentally put your variables into the headers textarea and vice versa. Make sure you're entering the variables into the correct input.

Comment: I am pretty sure that's on the correct place.